# Cannot add foreign key constraint mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, ddl

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error with this query. I'm stumped:

`Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`

My Code:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cname VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) COMMENT='Country List';

CREATE TABLE members (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Salt VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Salt) REFERENCES countries(cname)
) COMMENT='stuff';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A foreign key must reference a primary or unique key. For example, you could make `countries.cname` unique:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cname VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (cname) -- Here
) COMMENT='Country List';
```

Alternatively, you can drop the `salt` column and make the reference via the `id`:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Salt_id INT, -- Here
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Salt_Id) REFERENCES countries(id) -- And here
) COMMENT='stuff';
```